# Azure function every hour starting 00:10

Tags: azure, cron, azure-functions

I have to schedule azure function to run each hour but not at full hours but each time 10 minutes after a full hour. So 00:10 first run and next one 01:10, 02:10 ... 23:10. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of timer trigger azure function, you should specify the [cron expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions) as below:

```
0 10 0-23 * * *
```

For more details, you can learn it from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-examples).